# Laravel/php application not executing changes

Tags: laravel

I've been asked to debug an existing Laravel/PHP application.
I do not know much about Laravel so please excuse what may appear to be a dumb question.
I've modified the code in this file:
/var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/VC.php

However the application is not picking up the new code.
How do I make the code go into production?
I don't know the name of the project.

Thanks for any help

```
========================================================


The  website is accessed:
https://mywebsite/inhouse
```

On the server,
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan route:list|grep inhouse
|        | GET|HEAD| inhouse| inhouse.index| App\Http\Controllers\VC@index

I have this code file which I assume would get run:
/var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/VC.php

```
….
namespace App\Http\Controllers
….
class VC
```

I modified the index function to add trace code:

`public function index( )
{
  file_put_contents( '/tmp/VC_output',"Entering index...\n",FILE_APPEND);
  ...
}`

The output file /tmp/VC_output never gets created when I go to the url.
I didn't post the entire file as it is very large

Would anyone know why the add of the trace code never gets executed?

Comment: Please share the content of VC.php and the changes you are expecting and probably your router file as well

Comment: as well I would start with reading the requirements  and peeking into routes, and of course read the laravel docs

Comment: it is MVC pattern. Basically routes call the controllers and that controller provide the views by using data from modal or other logical operation. To see the changes you should probably see how that controller is being called from routes file.

Comment: Did you modify the code that was directly in production?

Comment: All,
Thanks for your assistance.
I've added the main parts of VC.php

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem.

No code compilation was required.
 I was thrown, in that the trace file was not created where it should be.

The trace file was found here:
/tmp/systemd-private-123456ff>/tmp/VC_output